# comparing two columns in excel sheet (text/string) and return the matched element in third column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in excel which I am trying to compare with one another and result the common element in third column. For example my sheet looks like

[image]

How do I compare Column D with E and if there is a matching string it will be printed in column F.

Edit 1: What function should I use to compare both case sensitive and non-sensitive strings.

Comment: you should use VLOOKUP or MATCH/INDEX and also with LOWER(for non case-sensitive to achieve this. you need to at least try a solution before i can suggest more.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of crude, but will tell you if the word in the first cell is in  the 2nd,  you can vary the left with mid, or right depending on your values.

```
=FIND(LEFT(C199,FIND(" ",C199,1)),O199,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In cell F1 place this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D1,$E$1:$E$100,0)),"",D1)
```

Then copy it down. This will show all non-case sensitive matches (for a column two list that has 100 values. Change the 100 to however long your column two list really is.)

To do the case-sensitive comparison try this:

```
=IF(EXACT(D1,LOOKUP(D1,$E$1:$E$100)),D1,"")
```

Comment: that wont compare both lists. that will just compared strings on the same row

Comment: thanks Steven, the code = IF(EXACT(D1,E1),D1,"") is not appropriate. I have edited it.

Comment: @DavidMcElhaney Thanks but using your method gived me the following error. Please see screenshot http://imgur.com/H1rUXQf

Comment: Sorry! Somehow I got $E$100 instead of $E1$100 in the second (case-sensitive one)....just found that by retesting. What happened was I changed my '7' to a '100' (I only used 7 rows) and must have goofed when re-typing it. Note to self: retest altered code! Btw...retest did work fine when I fixed that.

Comment: Just looked at it again. I think I had the formula right and maybe we are using different version of Excel? I am using 2010 office pro... really not sure what the problem is. For my seven row sheet this works: =IF(EXACT(D1,LOOKUP(D1,$E$1:$E$7)),D1,"")

Comment: I also see from the help on the LOOKUP function that the E column MUST be sorted ascending in order for this to work. Try sorting column E from A->Z. The thing is, when it's not sorted my test shows it missing some things but, again, no error. Very strange.